# JSON Serialized Email Format

Tags: .net, json, email, serialization, format

I am going to store emails in a document store that works with JSON.  Initially the emails I deal with are in MS System.Net.Mail.MailMessage format however in the future I might be grabbing emails from various different email servers and perhaps not even using .NET to put them into the store.

I want a comprehensive format that I can use and stick to that will record every piece of information I can get from an email.  Also, MailMessage does not jsonSerialize easily so I will have some sort of DTO anyway.

My question is, has anyone here had to store emails in a general format and if so what did they find most effective?  Are there any particular classes that they have come across that will store as much info as possible in an easy to serialize way?  And has anyone made some mistakes in the format they chose that I can avoid?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of messing around I realised that I was being a bit silly.  Most of the fields that are contained in various classes I have seen that represent emails are in fact derived from headers.  As a storage mechanism it makes sense just to drop anything that is in the headers and store the raw headers themselves.  This leaves the object as something pretty basic.